# Mounted filesystems - what are these?

Tags: mount

After running a program called hardinfo, I received this output four mounted systems:

```
none    /sys/fs/cgroup  0,00 % (4,0 KiB of 4,0 KiB)
udev    /dev    0,00 % (1,9 GiB of 1,9 GiB)
tmpfs   /run    0,25 % (390,7 MiB of 391,7 MiB)
none    /run/lock   0,08 % (5,0 MiB of 5,0 MiB)
none    /run/shm    0,04 % (1,9 GiB of 1,9 GiB)
none    /run/user   0,04 % (100,0 MiB of 100,0 MiB)
```

What are these and what are they for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are virtual filesystems created by the kernel and provided to the rest of the OS at run time. They don't actually exist on your harddrive, but are instead transparently created at boot time. There are quite a few of them, the ones you ran into: /dev, /run, and /sys, and a few more, such as /proc.

They are used primarily for providing the OS access to kernel-ly things such as block devices such as your harddrive (/dev), run time sockets/configs/etc (/run), hardware features such as a battery or display backlight and kernel features such as cgroups (/sys), and information on running processes (/proc).